# ContextMenuStrip how do you force update (size is wrong b/c I hide some of it's items)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, contextmenustrip

I have like 10 items in a ContextMenuStrip.  I have an Opening Event handler which decides which of the 10 items will be visible.  Based on application logic I may hide many of them by setting Visible = false and Enabled = false;

What happens is in the case that 6/10 are displayed.  Their will be an area 4 menu items height of blank space the first time I click the strip.  If I right click to make it appear the second time it shows up where it should be.  So, the strip basically has the position calculated for a 10 item strip when in reality it's only a 6 item strip.

[image: First Click It looks like this] [image: 2nd click it looks fine]

**How do I force it to recalculate?**

Here are some of the things I've tried:

```
        contextMenuStrip1.Refresh();
        contextMenuStrip1.Update();
        contextMenuStrip1.PerformLayout();
        contextMenuStrip1.AutoSize = true;

        ToolStripItem tempItem = contextMenuStrip1.Items.Add("temp");
        contextMenuStrip1.Items.Remove(tempItem);

        contextMenuStrip1.Refresh();
        contextMenuStrip1.Update(); 

        contextMenuStrip1.Invalidate();
```

Answer (score 4):

I've found that

```
AutoSize = false;
AutoSize = true;
```

after all item manipulations works. Haven't found any other solution.

In my case, I add items on opening (dynamic list of windows), and sometimes item caption was longer than the menu.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I'm not in a position to test that anymore.  But, will refer back when I do.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using Invalidate()?

From the MSDN:

> Invalidates the entire surface of the control and causes the control
>   to be redrawn. (Inherited from Control.)

Perhaps you need to use then WM_PAINT message, I have found that sometimes you need to use SendMessage (Interop) with Winforms.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145213(v=vs.85).aspx